# скрыть один элемент в each функции если условие верно

Tags: jquery, ajax

Во не понимаю в чем проблема, есть динамически наполняемый в шаблоне блок:

```
var card =
<video class="mp4Class" controls="controls">
          <source src="${mp4ar} "type="video/mp4">
  $('.container').append(card);
```

Затем идет такое условие и нужно скрыть один элемент в условии:

```
$(document).find(".mp4Class source").each(function(item, index) {
              if (!this.src.includes('undefined')) {
                console.log("src is:", item, index);
              } else {
                console.log("src is undefined:", item, index);
                //$(this).hide() - не работает
               //$('mp4Class').hide() - скрывает все элементы класса
              }
            });
```

Comment: на самом деле в jquery функциях первым параметром идет `index`, а только потом элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас же прописано в `each(function(item, index){..}` что вложенной функции передаются такие параметры как `item` и `index`, следовательно можно их и использовать для определения текущего элемента для скрытия:

```
$(item).hide();
//или
$('.mp4Class').eq(index).hide();
```

UPD: У вас аргументы для функции в `each` в неправильном порядке:

```js
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, item ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + item );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(item).hide();` я тоже пробовал раньше, не знаю почему не работает
только что попробовал ваш `$('.mp4Class').eq(index).hide();` с таким же успехом

Comment: @Romikromikromik Обновил ответ.

Comment: аргументы у меня работают в обеих случаях)  jquery у меня такая `jquery-3.3.1.js` , а вот фнукция к сожалению не работает

Comment: Что значит работают в обеих случаях? В вашем коде у переменных index и item противоположный смысл: index содержит элемент, а item содержит значение индекса. Each присутствует в JQuery с 1.0.

Comment: о спасибо, теперь `$('.mp4Class').eq(index).hide();` работает `$(value).hide();` - нет

Comment: Хм... без приведение кода html трудно сказать в чем у вас еще проблема. value здесь просто имя переменной, в данном случае можно оставить ваш item

Comment: как говорится : "И так сойдет))". В любом случае спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, присвой элементу который хочешь скрыть id и в качестве селектора используй id.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду `id="mp4Id"` а в условии внизу `$('#mp4Id').hide();` то скрывается только лиш первый элемент, это надо опять в цикл всё забрасывать?